# Having a problem with a basic join

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a table called **tblSport** which contains the columns **pkSportID** and **fldName**.
I have a table called **tblRespondentSport** which contains the columns **fkRespondentID** and **fkSportID**.

I want to return the sport ID, the name of the sport, and the number of respondents.

Here's my query:

```
SELECT s.pkSportID AS id, s.fldSport AS sport, r.COUNT(*) AS count FROM tblSport AS s LEFT JOIN tblRespondentSport AS r ON s.pkSportID = r.fkSportID
```

I'm getting a MySQL 1064 error and it says its near the * in COUNT().  I'm new to joins so I'm sure its something trivial.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a group by. When you do a count(*), you have to do a group by on some field to aggregate the count. In this case the group by should be on the fkSportID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing Group BY

```
SELECT s.pkSportID AS id, s.fldSport AS sport, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM tblSport AS s LEFT JOIN tblRespondentSport AS r 
ON s.pkSportID = r.fkSportID
GROUP BY s.pkSportID, s.fldSport
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try that.  Also, could you explain the GROUP BY?

Comment: @birderic, I corrected query. "group by" is grouped rows and calculated aggregated value.

Comment: When you are doing count, you are looking to aggregate a certain field and count the number of occurences. Doing group by helps accomplish this. For example if you group by SportID, and you have two occurences of SportID number 5, it will display sportID 5 and under count, it will display two.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `r.COUNT(*) to COUNT(r.*).` or even just `COUNT(*)`